# Drupal 7 - Slideshow with caption

Tags: drupal, view, slideshow, caption

I am attempting to create a View Slideshow for a website I am designing and the have it so an image-specific caption/description is placed over each image. I've been Googling some solutions and the only thing I could find was a solution for placing captions above or under the image, not on top of it. I feel as if there should be a very simple solution for this sort of thing, however, I have been unable to find it.

First, I would like to know if this is even possible with View Slideshow and if so then how to accomplish this.

Any information that is provided will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS! When you think about it, it's not about the views module. Even html doesn't allow you to put two things at the same place. Not without CSS anyway.

I managed to do quite the same on [this website](http://best-grenoble.fr/public/fr) (cf. the slideshow of the homepage). I only used the `position:relative` and then for example`top:XXXpx` and `left:XXXpx` propreties to position the text wherever I want in the slideshow container.

If you are not familiar with theses CSS propreties, [here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a little demonstration of how it works. Have fun!

Comment: Make sense, thanks! But how do I access the CSS for the content type I created? For instance, I created a new content-type "Front Page Slide" and gave it fields "Title" and "Description" and "Slide Image" and have it set to slideshow. How do I know what the name of each field is within the view so I can change the positioning?